# laptop speakers muted after headphones unplugged (Debian derivative BunsenLabs)

Tags: audio, alsa, alsamixer

Strange audio trouble on an older laptop...

I just installed a fresh BunsenLabs on an old eeePC Asus 1001PXD.

I noticed that I wasn't getting any sound from the speakers. When I plugged in headphones, those worked! So it wasn't that the audio itself wasn't being recognized.

I played with pavucontrol and alsamixer, but wasn't getting any joy.

After a bunch of googling, I did come across a possible fix:

```
Try using

options snd-hda-intel model=auto probe_mask=1 

in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, and then reboot. Any different?

from here:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/speakers-not-working-default-audio-device-is-headphone-4175673286/
```

(I should note: There wasn't a alsa-base.conf file created until I tried this solution.)

I also tried turning up the 'headphones' in alsamixer while they were unplugged.

Then the speakers started working!

Continuing to test, I'm noticing that when I plug headphones in, the sound works fine on the headphones. (And mutes the laptop speakers.) When I unplug  the headphones, the laptop speakers stay muted.

In alsamixer, I can see the 'headphones' column go muted when I unplug the headphones. I've tried both settings of the 'automute' toggle in alsamixer, and no joy there.

(Though perhaps I need to change the setting, exit and save alsa settings? Maybe the toggle isn't active until it's saved?)

I'm not certain if my attempt with the alsa-base.conf did anything, or if the alsamixer fix was always going to work.

In terms of next steps:

Is there any way to stop the behavior of the laptop speakers staying muted when the headphone jack is removed?

I can go into alsamixer each time to fix it, but I'd prefer to find the fix that brings back expected behavior!